# Is the set of partial order relations over $ \mathbb{N}$ countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the set of partial order relations over $ \mathbb{N}$ countable?
I think it's uncountable but don't know how to prove this. I would be very helpful if someone could also give some kind of a strategy for proving uncountability, in particular how to find injective or surjective functions that help proving this.

Comment: Please include your question in the body of the question, instead of putting it only in the title.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I edited it